# wpf Finding a button from wrap panel

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mouseevent, wrappanel

I have `Buttons` in `WrapPanel`, those are creating dynamically. I want to change the height/width of a particular `Button` on `Click_event`.

Here is what i m doing:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
                btn = new Button();
                btn.MinHeight = 22;
                btn.MinWidth = 22;

                btn.Content = i.ToString();
                int _id = id++;
                btn.Name = "btn"+_id.ToString();
                wrpQuestionsMap.Children.Add(btn);

                btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
    }

    private void btnNext_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.view.CurrentPosition < this.view.Count - 1)
            {
                this.view.MoveCurrentToNext();

                Button b = (Button)this.wrpQuestionsMap.FindName("btn"+view.CurrentPosition.ToString());
                if (b != null)
                {
                    b.Width = 30;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried above but it's getting null, don't know why.
Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and you want to change the size of the clicked Button:
For this line of code:

```
btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
```

you should have a method like this:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button btn=(Button)sender; // this is the clicked Button
  btn.Width=30.0;            //changes its Width
}
```

**Edit:**

```
foreach (Button btn in wrpQuestionsMap.Children)
{
    string name= btn.Content.ToString();
    if  (name == "yourName")   // yourName is the name you are searching for
    {
         btn.Width = 30.0   //change size
         break;             // no need to search more
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
From the code in your question, it seems that the Content of your Buttons is a number `btn.Content = i.ToString();`. You said in your comment that `view.CurrentPosition.ToString()` is the number of your current question. If you want to change the Width of this Button, use:

```
foreach (Button btn in wrpQuestionsMap.Children)
{
    string name= btn.Content.ToString(); // it must be a number, check it in the debug, and if it is not, Let me know
    if  (name == view.CurrentPosition.ToString())
    {
         btn.Width = 30.0   //change size
         break;             // no need to search more
    }
}
```

If you want to change the Width of another Button, You should let me know what is written in that Button.

Comment: plz check [here](http://www.satkartravel.com/images/ss.png) screen shot of my application first. <br /> In this application user select a topic from left side to generate the online test of that topic. <br /> After selecting the Topic, i am adding the buttons dynamically at right side.<br /> I want to change the button height/width of the button in right side which no. of question is currently on screen. That's it.

Comment: @Deepak Would you pleas explain the last sentence (I want to change ... ) a little more?

Comment: Suppose user on 5th no. of question, in that case the width of button no. 5 should change in quick view section of application, All the buttons are in Wrap Panel in Quick view.

Comment: this code changing the every button width<br/> I have done this <br/> '

                foreach (Button btn in wrpQuestionsMap.Children)
                {
                    string name= btn.Content.ToString();
                    if  (name == view.CurrentPosition.ToString())  
                    {
                        btn.Width = 30.0;
                        break;
                    }
                }'

Comment: Use `if (name == "btn" + view.CurrentPosition.ToString())`. if you failed, then answer: What is `view.CurrentPosition`? is it the number of the current question?

Comment: sorry for late response, still it's changing the width of all buttons in wrap panel. Yes, view.CurrentPosition is the no. of current question. I want to change the width of a particular button. plz help and thanks for your response.